# Processing my dataframes with conditions - python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, physics

This is my first post and im not so much into programming and python. Hope i can discribe this well pls be patient with me :)

For my studies i use jupyter notebook (numpy pandas etc.) to process and plot my data.
Here it has something to do with xray beams and a Geiger-Müller-counter.
It looks like this :

```
# loading my txt
data1_1_KBr = pd.read_csv("1_1_SpektrumCuKBr_Daten.txt",skiprows=2,usecols=[0,1], 
                           names=["Winkel1_1_KBr","Rate1_1_KBr"],delimiter="\t",decimal=",")
#putting into dataframe
df1_1_KBr = pd.DataFrame(data1_1_KBr,columns=["Winkel1_1_KBr","Rate1_1_KBr"])

#this is the correction of my values
N_1_1_KBr = (df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr/(1-T*df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr))
```

The correction should only apply for higher values of "Rate1_1_KBr".

The processed data should be a panda dataframe or array like data that just looks the same like my orignal data with the entries that are corrected.

I tried to write loop and i failed.

It should be something like this (no code just thoughts) :

If the values of "Rate1_1_KBr" are smaller then 200, then put these into my new dataframe, if the values of "Rate1_1_KBr" are bigger then 200 then process them with my correction and afterwards put them into my new dataframe.

Would be awesome if somebody got an nice explanation for a beginner like me :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with numpy, but you can use indexing with dataframes the same way. Also, the second line of your code is redundant as the `pd.read_csv` returns a dataframe itself. So the code you want looks like this:

```
df1_1_KBr = pd.read_csv("1_1_SpektrumCuKBr_Daten.txt",skiprows=2,usecols=[0,1], 
                           names=["Winkel1_1_KBr","Rate1_1_KBr"],delimiter="\t",decimal=",")
correction_df = df1_1_KBr[df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr>200]
N_1_1_KBr = df1_1_KBr.copy()
N_1_1_KBr[correction_df.index, 'Rate1_1_KBr'] = (correction_df.Rate1_1_KBr/(1-T*correction_df.Rate1_1_KBr))
```

Note that there is no need to use `apply` as it is much slower than indexing this way.

Also not sure if `T` is a constant value or part of a dataframe. If the former, this code should work.

Comment: thx for answer :) "T" is a constant. it does not work : TypeError: unhashable type: 'Int64Index'. There is an missing or misplaced " ' ". I tried both but it does not work.

Comment: @DennisS.Can you provide a dummy version of the csv file? Or just update the question by adding a dataframe manually. Also, which line throws the error?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Dennis,

```py
def proc_rate(rate, threshold, T):
    if rate<threshold:
        return rate
    else:
        return (rate/(1-T*rate))

ans = df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr.apply(proc_rate, threshold=200, T=T)
```

if You want to write the series back to the original data frame:

```py
df1_1_KBr.loc[:, 'Rate1_1_KBr'] = df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr.apply(proc_rate, threshold=200, T=T)
```

You can also filter the rates and then apply the correction method:

```
sub_frame = df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr[df1_1_KBr.Rate1_1_KBr<200].apply(proc_rate, threshold=200, T=T)
```